# Upgrading my graphics card (agp)

Tags: 11.10, graphics, radeon

I'm looking to upgrade my graphics card. I currently have a GeForce FX 5950 Ultra installed. I don't want to buy a new motherboard, much less a new computer, so I'm stuck with agp.

I'm looking at HIS's Radeon HD 4650 and 4670, but I have no idea how well they work with Ubuntu. The man page for the radeon says it is compatible, but I've read bits of people having some issues. Does anybody have any experience with them, or any recommendations for other agp cards?

Comment: They should work fine. With the open source drivers and with the Catalyst drivers.

Answer (score 1):

they do run almost any games such as crysis2 battlefield 3 etc very smoothly no problems. Mine also ran nfs run but it hanged a bit